# HTML Email - different images for desktop and mobile

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I think I have tried all possible existing solutions so I am here to ask if anyone know what is the best way to display a:

- simple (clickable or not clickable) image
- using a different image for desktop and mobile
- compatible with most popular email clients

The solution posted here: [A Slick, New Image Swapping Technique for Responsive Emails](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/a_slick_new_image_swapping_technique_for_responsive_emails) seems to be the best so far but it has one little big issue, the 2 images are always downloaded (I don't mean displayed), either you are on mobile or desktop.

```
<a href="http://www.emailonacid.com">
  <span id="switcher">
    <img id="houdini" src="http://www.sample.com/desktop.jpg" alt="">
  </span>
</a>

 <style>
  @media only screen and (max-device-width: 489px) {
    span[id=switcher] {
      display:block;
      background-image: url(http://www.sample.com/mobile.jpg) !important;
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-position: center !important;
      width: 300px !important;
      height: 250px !important;
    }
    img[id=houdini] {display: none !important;}1
  }
</style>
```

The "img" tag always download the image even if it is not displayed (display:none).

I have tried many other ways, using background-images on tables but this seems to require VML code for microsoft and the solution looks really messy and sometimes not even working on android.

Is anyone able to help?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mony18o7/)

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried using a media query changing the bg image of the span - and leave the <img> tag out all together? - So, effectively one css rule with the bg image, and then a media query overwriting that bg image for mobile?

Comment: Media queries are not supported in all email clients, therefore if the image would only be displayed with media queries code it won't appear on all email clients

Comment: Also, @asimovwasright, background image is not supported by all clients, (especially old ones like Microsoft Outlook on Windows) therefore that won't be possible

Comment: Is there anyway you could control the server which is dishing out the image, then you could use http sniffing to serve the image based on the UA. (Although I have never attempted that myself, I am pretty sure it's possible.) :-)

Comment: @asimovwasright Same here, never tested before but may be a solution, as suggested below by gyula :-) ..it's worth a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others mentioned, hiding image will never be stable. My solution is to create a small server-side script which will serve different images for different devices. I think that is the most stable and robust solution.

You can identify the os, device and screen width from the header of the request, although any browser/email client could send fake info.

We use this package to parse user agent info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ua-parser
and we can fetch these info with it:
https://github.com/EDMdesigner/supertracker/blob/master/models/session.js

Based on the device field, you can serve different images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very interesting and I have never thought about it, it's definitely one possible solution that should be taken into consideration. I will wait to see if any other solutions come up otherwise I will chose yours as best one.

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to have different images for desktop and mobile and not have them both downloaded, for email. Getting around that requires Javascript, which isn't supported in any major email client.

I should also like to point out that image swapping, no matter which method you use, isn't supported on some major mail apps, especially Gmail. From design standpoint, the best practice is to use the same image for desktop and mobile.

Comment: I am not 100% sure there is no way to do that.... let's see if there is someone with a solution :-) but thank you for your answer anyway. (and yes, I am aware of the compatibility issues, it's definitely something to keep in mind)

Comment: This, unfortunately, is the correct answer.  There are a ton of cool things that email can do, but it usually comes with a ton of duct tape and gum and requires many levels of graceful degradation to ensure appealing display on all email clients. Image swapping is one of those things.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, sort of, and it’s a bit tricky to pull off. Gmail is probably the biggest hurdle since [it strips out the `<style>` tag](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) and thus, doesn't support media queries.

First, one caveat: Google Apps webmail + Mobile Gmail will render the same, but we can get regular Gmail webmail to be different.

Gmail strips class and id attributes from all elements but leaves some other attributes intact: `style`, `title`, `lang`, `width`, `height`, `alt`, `href`. **So we can target regular Gmail webmail using something like `[lang~="x-houdini"] {display: none !important;}`.**

So use Mobile Gmail as the base for what you want to show, then you can overwrite regular Gmail webmail by targeting it to hide the Mobile Gmail image and show the regular Gmail webmail image.

Again, this won’t work on Google Apps webmail, it will display the same as Gmail App.

[This article on Fresh Inbox](http://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-emails-in-gmail-using-css-attribute-selectors/) explains how to target specific versions of Gmail. Worth a read if you go down this path and have questions!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no issues with Gmail as both webmail and app are not using media queries so they will display desktop images only. Interesting the Gmail target, never knew about it. However this won't help me with my question unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

How about just having the image with width 100%? 
I tried it and it seems to work for different width's. 
I even tried it with chrome's responsive mode and even there it seems to work for iphone sized device although the image quality was not as sharp.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ResponsiveImage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="Tulips.jpg" width="100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Having only one image with 100% width is different than what I am trying to do: having 2 different images for desktop and mobile version of the email.

Comment: My understanding based on other's answers is that you'd have to take an approach where the style and content remain fixed but the image size varies (for example having the image center align). That way when the mobile or desktop's browser requests for the image you can determine the user-agent and then return the relevant image from the server. As such all the content will have to be responsive and the styles have to be specified per element.

Comment: ok, I understand you meant to use this for gyula.nemeth solution